# Discrete maths proving a random observation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose you had 6 points. Each point can choose to either visit another point, or choose not to visit another point. However, it can't visit itself. In addition, visiting another point works in both directions; if point 1 visits point 2, that implies point 2 visits point 1.

I want to prove that for any arrangement, either A) there is a group of 3 points that have each visited each other or B) there is a group of 3 points that have not visited each other.

I've convinced myself its true by drawing a bunch of random hexagons, but exactly how do I go about proving this?

Comment: Do you now graphs? In particular do you know complament graph?

Comment: no I don't know anything about graph theory

Comment: I gave you an answer below. You should know that this is a question in graph theory and releted to Ramzy numbers. I also think you should tag it also as combinatorics and graph theory question and not strictly discrete-mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two cases:

a. Assume that there is a point $v$ that connected to 3 or more other points
say $v_1,v_2,v_3$. if a pair of the points $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is connected (say $v_1,v_2$) then you have a $3$ points which are connected. If not, then the points $v_1,v_2,v_3$ do not visit each other.

b. Assume that there is no point which is connected to three other points. Take a point $v$. Then she is not connected to at least $3$ other points, say $v_1,v_2,v_3$. If a pair of the points $v_1,v_2,v_3$ is not connected (say $v_1,v_2$) then you have a $3$ points which are not connected. If not, then the points $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are all connected.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I'm wondering how did you choose to you use those cases for your proof though. Is it something through experience or is it something that arises often in another discipline?

Comment: As I said this is a well known result in the theory of Ramsy numbers on graphs. I just change the notations fron graph theory to your notations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following table:

```
 Number of singles | Number of doubles | Number of triples | Implies
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------
         6         |         0         |         0         |    B
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------
         4         |         1         |         0         |    B
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------
         3         |         0         |         1         |   A,B
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------
         2         |         2         |         0         |    B
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------
         1         |         1         |         1         |   A,B
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------
         0         |         3         |         0         |    B
-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|---------
         0         |         0         |         2         |    A
```

Where:

- *Single* means an unvisited point
- *Double* means a group of $2$ points which visit each other
- *Triple* means a group of $3$ points which visit each other

Obviously, cases of $4$ or $5$ or $6$ points visiting each other, imply A (and possibly B).

---

Another way to show it is by depicting all possible ways to write $6$ as a sum of positive integers:

- $1,1,1,1,1,1 \implies   B$
- $1,1,1,1,2   \implies   B$
- $1,1,1,3     \implies A,B$
- $1,1,2,2     \implies   B$
- $1,2,3       \implies A,B$
- $2,2,2       \implies   B$
- $3,3         \implies A  $
- $4,1,1       \implies A,B$
- $4,2         \implies A  $
- $5,1         \implies A  $
- $6           \implies A  $

A sum that contains a value of $3$ or more implies A.

A sum that contains $3$ or more elements implies B.

Since any sum must be either one or both of those, A and/or B always hold.

This is because any sequence of positive integers whose sum is equal to $N$, either contains a value equal to or greater than $\lceil\sqrt{N}\rceil$, or contains a number of elements equal to or greater than $\lceil\sqrt{N}\rceil$.

Comment: And $\lceil\sqrt{6}\rceil=3$.